# Force ffmpeg to generate WebVTT for each subtitle track

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I use the following ffmpeg command to generate an HLS stream from a video:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 \
    -y -b:a 64k -acodec aac -vcodec copy \
    -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod -start_number 0 -hls_base_url http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -hls_list_size 0 \
    -f hls -crf 20 -hls_flags split_by_time -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)"\
    -threads 4 \
    target/stream.m3u8
```

It works perfectly, and to my pleasure and surprise ffmpeg generates a second m3u8 file corresponding to the subtitles that are embeded in the video file, with the appropriate .vtt files.
The problem is that when i input a video file with more than one subtitle tracks, i only get files for the first one.
How can i force ffmpeg to output ALL tracks as m3u8 / .vtt files ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Add `-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s`

Comment: Thanks you :) I get this error: `[webvtt @ 0x7fb9fa014600] Exactly one WebVTT stream is needed.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --`